# Is “It is happy to see that there is nothing sectarian about it” (meaning "the speaker is happy to see ...") grammatical and idiomatic?

Tags: word-usage, grammaticality, adjectives

Most of the native speakers around me say (i) below is not idiomatic.

(i) It is happy to hear that. (meaning "I (the speaker) am happy to hear that.")

Today, however, I came across sentences (ii) and (iii) below in an article.

(ii) It is happy to see that there is nothing sectarian about it, but that the whole christian church unites in its advancement.
[The Christian Intelligencer,](https://books.google.it/books?id=PHKy6AJU4mQC&q=%22it%20is%20happy%22#v=snippet&q=%22it%20is%20happy%22&f=false)

(iii) It is happy to think of what the committee was avoiding in the way of ruthless analysis…
[Parliamentary Debates (Hansard)](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22It+is+happy+to+think+of+what+the+committee%22+)

Are these sentences grammatical and idiomatic?

Comment: _Which_ article, please? Was the writer a native speaker of English? They are not idiomatic in standard English.

Comment: @Kate Bunting  Thanks for your comments.  I think the writers of (ii) and (iii) are native speakers of English. Sentence (ii) was from an article written by The Rev. Mr. Breckenridge, in the book titled  "Speeches on Special Occasions". Sentence (iii) was taken from Hansard, UK Parliament.

Comment: I have done Google Ngram searches for _it is happy to see_ and _it is happy to think_. Some of the results refer to an animal or organisation being happy about something, but to my surprise I did find some instances of the expression being used in the sense _it is good to see..._ or _I am happy to see..._. I'm not familiar with this usage and would not have thought that it was idiomatic.

Comment: @Kate Bunting Thank you again for your help. Many native speakers of English around me find (ii) and (iii) to be unacceptable. But, some say they are OK. I wanted to know how bad others think they are. And I wondered whether it is a matter of idiolect or personal style.

Comment: @SunnyLee You should include citations in the question body. These comments are not permanent and may disappear at any time.

Comment: All of these examples sound very strange to me. I'm from the UK.  I'd use: "It's nice to see", or "it's great to see", or "it's good to see".  "I am happy to see" is fine.  If you use "it's happy to see [something]" - I'd assume you are talking about an animal, not a human.  **Look at that dog wagging its tail. It's happy to see you!**

Answer (score 2):

I have encountered this sort of use of "happy" in the past, but mostly in texts from the 18th or early 19th century.

I tried [this Google Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=+It+is+happy+to+see%2C+It+is+happy+to+think%2C+It+is+happy+to+&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&case_insensitive=on&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t4%3B%2CIt%20is%20happy%20to%20see%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3BIt%20is%20happy%20to%20see%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bit%20is%20happy%20to%20see%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2CIt%20is%20happy%20to%20think%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3BIt%20is%20happy%20to%20think%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bit%20is%20happy%20to%20think%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2CIt%20is%20happy%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bit%20is%20happy%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BIt%20is%20happy%20to%3B%2Cc0#t4%3B%2CIt%20is%20happy%20to%20see%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3BIt%20is%20happy%20to%20see%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bit%20is%20happy%20to%20see%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2CIt%20is%20happy%20to%20think%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3BIt%20is%20happy%20to%20think%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bit%20is%20happy%20to%20think%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2CIt%20is%20happy%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bit%20is%20happy%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BIt%20is%20happy%20to%3B%2Cc0) which shows some usage of "it is happy to". Of course this may include such usages as "when you meet a dog, it is happy to see you" which are not to the point here. Looking through the related Google Books searchs, and excluding examples clearly not of the type the question discussed, I find (among other examples):

- *The New Buddhism* by By David Brazier (2002)

> It is happy to see science advance and it wants that science applied for the benefit of all sentient life.

- *Notes on the Pentateuch: The Book of Genesis* by
  C. H. Mackintosh (2015)

> It is happy to see this. Happy to see how the Church's security and blessing stand inseparably connected with Christ and His glory.

- *The Christian's Friend and Instructor: Christian Magazine* by John Nelson Darby, , ‎H. C. Anstey, ‎T. H. Reynolds (2015)

> But it is happy to see that the heart of Christ is not wearied out by what it again and again got from man and in man.

But in the output of these searches the majority of results has "it" refer back to an object such as "a dog" or "the government" and were not of the form discussed in the question. So I went to [*The Federalist Papers*](https://www.gutenberg.org/files/1404/1404-h/1404-h.htm) where I thought I recalled some such uses of 'Happy". I found (again omitting uses not at all similar to those in the question):

> - Happy will it be if our choice should be directed by a judicious estimate of our true interest [#1]
> - We most earnestly recommend to you calmness and unanimity in this great and weighty affair, that the union may be brought to a happy conclusion, ... [#5]
> - The federal Constitution forms a happy combination in this respect [#10]
> - And yet, in such a system, it is even happy when such compromises can take place: for upon some occasions things will not admit of accommodation [#22]
> - Happy it is when the interest which the government has in the preservation of its own power, coincides with a proper distribution of the public burdens [#36]
> - Happy will it be for ourselves, and more honorable for human nature, if we have wisdom and virtue enough to set so glorious an example to mankind! [#36]
> - They are equally unanimous in prescribing the remedy, by which this happy effect is to be produced. [#38]
> - The distance of the United States from the powerful nations of the world gives them the same happy security. [#41]
> - Happy would it be for the unfortunate Africans, if an equal prospect lay before them of being redeemed from the oppressions of their European brethren! [#42]
> - Happy would it be if such a remedy for its infirmities could be enjoyed by all free governments; if a project equally effectual could be established for the universal peace of mankind!  [#43]

I conclude that although grammatically valid, such usage as:

> It is happy to see that there is nothing sectarian about it.

are unusual and will often sound old-fashioned, and should be avoided unless the desired style is enhanced by such usage. In particular I would advise learner to avoid such constructions.

Comment: +1 for the research.

Comment: Note that most of the examples you quote from the _Federalist papers_ are effectively "It is happy that" rather than "It is happy to see that". This is still odd in modern usage, but to my ear not quite as odd.

Comment: @Colin Fine True. But these examples show clearly that "happy" was, at the time, used in the sense of "good, fortunate".  I suspect that other works of the same period would  similar usages. I I had ebook searchble ersions of Jane Ausrin I might check there.

Comment: No instances in _Emma_. One in _Pride and Prejudice_, but it is personal: "It is happy for you that you possess the talent of flattering with delicacy". None in _Persuasion_ .

Comment: @Colin Thank you.